# Making room for a div

Tags: css

I have a jQuery slider near the top of my page. But when the page first loads, it takes a few seconds for the slider to load and during that time, the divs underneath it are near the top.

Is there a way to make room immediately for the slider div so the elements below are placed properly from the start? This isn't preloading as the slider is one of the first elements on the page and I don't believe that preloading would do any good.

Here is the page in action: http://americanart.si.edu/index_newsplash3r.cfm

Thx.

Comment: You would have to set a height for the slider container.

Comment: **a few seconds**? I had given up on discovering what the slider was and had switched to another tab long before it appeared! Are you sure you want blank space there from the start?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [min-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp) and [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) as well as height and width on your CSS. This should force the div to be a certain height.

Apply these attributes to the CSS for the element:
`height: 100px; min-height: 100px;` for example.